# How to remove letsencrypt ssl installed on Ubuntu apache2 server

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have apache server and installed letsencrypt totally from my server following the [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Now I want to delete the ssl installation.
What I did was 
(1)I deleted `/etc/letsencrypt folder`.

(2)I removed config file using

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default-le-ssl.conf
```

(3)I did

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

But when I access my site like www.example.com
I still have 
https://www.example.com, I have error as `Secure Connection Failed`
Then my site is not loaded.

How can I totally `remove letsencrypt ssl and load my site.`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't run LetsEncrypt to update certificates, it won't do anything. What it has already setup in terms of configuration may still be there however.

There may be othe files that it has created, or changed in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ - or at least that are symlinked ibto that directory.

If you have deleted the /etc/letsencrypt directory, then it is also likely that there are other vhosts configured in the 'sites-enabled' directory that still refer to it. You can `grep` for such terms as 'SSLCertificateFile' or 'letsencrypt' (the directory path), and confirm that your Apache configuration is very likely to start correctly with `sudo apache2ctl configtest`, editing it where the SSL configuration exists to fully remove it and end up with a a fully non-TLS/SSL website(s) configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Open your 000-default.conf and comment some code which should look something like below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =YOURSITE.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.YOURSITE.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Save the config file.
Run following two commands.

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```